# Expression must be modifiable lvalue

Tags: array-address

```
typedef struct state1_s {
    u8 size;
    u8 state;
} state1_t;
typedef struct state2_s {
    u8 size;
    u8 state[2];
} state2_t;
typedef struct state3_s {
    u8 code;
    u8 count;
}state3_t;
```

I have these three structures.
When i do the following

```
state1_t comp[8];
state2_t *avail;
state3_t *health;

&comp = (state1_t *)(&(avail->state[2])+1);
```

i get a expression must be modifiable lvalue error.

I get the same error when i do

```
&comp = (state1_t *)(&(heaalth->count) +1);
```

how do i fix this?
I want the address of comp to be at the end of one structure. How do i do that?

Comment: You can't change the address of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`state1_t comp[8];`

In this declaration `comp` is an array of 8 struct's `state1_t` with base address of the array being `comp` which cannot be modifiable. Hence the modifiable lvalue error when you try changing address of `comp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the address of an array. You should use a pointer instead:

```
state1_t *comp;
```

Then you can do:

```
comp = (state1_t *)(&(avail->state[2]));
```

You don't need to add 1 to the address -- `state[2]` is already the end of the structure, since `state[1]` is the last element of that array.